# Why Null Set is zero Dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A null set is always considered to be zero dimensional,but a set containing zero vector only is taken to be non-empty set.If something is present there,then why it does'nt make a contribution in part of dimension.

Comment: How is the empty set considerez to be zero-dimensional? It is not a vector space.

Comment: The span of the null set is defined to be the zero vector space, which is zero dimensional. The null set is not zero dimensional.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft why cannot be the empty set be considered a vector space over some arbitrary field? I mean, the axioms that define a vector space, if Im not wrong, holds vacuously.

Comment: They don't. $(\varnothing,+)$ is not an abelian group.

Comment: Also note that in the context of *affine spaces*, $\varnothing$ is an affine space of dimension $-1$, while $\{p\}$ is an affine space of dimension $0$.

Comment: @Masacroso No, they don't hold: the **existence** of neutral element cannot hold here.

Comment: If V is a vector space then V itself and 0 vector are always two extreme subspaces of it.Being a subspace means being a vector space itself.

Answer (score 4):

Note the distinction between saying

- "The empty set is zero-dimensional" (which is false, as Tobias Kildetoft says, because the empty set does not normally admit the structure of a vector space), and
- "A zero-dimensional vector space (i.e., a one-element vector space) *has the empty set as basis*" (which is true, and the reason a one-element vector space is "zero-dimensional").